# SSE4, SSE5 & AMD Cool n Quiet

Tags: c++, cpu, processor, instructions

Well, i we're wondering if C++ can check if the computer has [SSE4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4), [SSE5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE5), and [Cool 'n' Quiet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool%27n%27Quiet). It's possible? How? I saw the [isProcessorFeaturePresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but i don't see anything about those there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this by checking the `cpuid` processor features flags, the msdn page for `__cpuid` has a long example on enumerating them

Comment: I'm not sure if Cool 'n Quiet is supported nor what it is, but I went to look so here it is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6aek1h(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @kenny: Seems ms is slacking in updating their `cpuid` and `cpuidex` docs, as they stop at sse4.2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx tbh, your best bet for up to date flags is the amd assembly manuals, iirc volume 2 and 3 are instructions